# Nested resources in ember.js, adding comments to a post with fixture data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to write a simple blog with Ember. I can't figure out how to nest comments resource inside the post resource. (I used ember-cli to generate the app)

/app/router.js

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: ENV.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts', { path: '/' }, function() {
        this.resource('post', { path: 'posts/:post_id' }, function() {
            this.resource('comments');
        });
    });
});

export default Router;
```

/app/templates/posts.hbs

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <h2>Posts</h3>
    {{#each}}
        <h4>{{#link-to 'post' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</h4>
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9">
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

/app/templates/post.hbs

```
<h2>
    {{#if isEditing}}
        {{input value=title}}
    {{else}}
        {{title}}
    {{/if}}
</h2>
<p>
    {{#if isEditing}}
        {{textarea value=body}}
    {{else}}
        {{body}}
    {{/if}}
</p>
<p>
    {{publishDate}}
</p>

{{#if isEditing}}
    <button {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Save</button>
{{else}}
    <button {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
{{/if}}

{{!-- Should be outlet to Comments? --}}
{{outlet}}
```

/app/templates/comments.hbs

```
<h1>Comments</h1>
```

/app/model/post.js

```
var Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    magic: DS.attr('string'),
    publishDate: DS.attr('date'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});

Post.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Writing a blog in Ember",
            body: "I am writting a blog",
            magic: "heloo212",
            publishDate: "05/22/2104",
            comments: [1, 2]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "I'm shouting Ember",
            body: "I am shouting about Ember",
            publishDate: "05/22/2104",
            comments: 3
        }
    ]
});

export default Post;
```

/app/models/comment.js

```
var Comment = DS.Model.extend({
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    author: DS.attr('string'),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
    post: DS.belongsTo('post')
})

Comment.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {
            id: 1,
            body: "Woohoo",
            author: "Matthew",
            createdAt: "01/01/2015",
            post: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            body: "Great Stuff",
            author: "Mark",
            createdAt: "01/02/2015",
            post: 1
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            body: "A comment",
            author: "Luke",
            createdAt: "01/04/2015",
            post: 2
        }
    ]
});

export default Comment;
```

app/routes/comments.js

```
var CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('comment');
    }
});

export default CommentsRoute;
```

I expected to see my comments.hbs template appearing at the bottom of the post.hbs (currently just trying to put out Comments but I don't see anything and ember inspector is telling me:

> Could not find "post.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered
>   Object {fullName: "template:post.index"}

Comment: will you show the `posts` and `comments` template also.  And does the `posts` template work?

Comment: Added both of those templates. The posts template works and renders the selected post as expected.

Comment: I don't see any link to the comments section, and when you say ember inspector says that, are you referring to in the console, or what are you doing in ember inspector that's saying that?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood it. I thought nesting comments inside post resource would mean that the {{outlet}} in post.hbs would display the comments? The console debug is showing that message not inspector, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested routes/resources aren't automatically rendered.  Think of this example

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts', { path: '/' }, function() {
        this.resource('post', { path: 'posts/:post_id' }, function() {
            this.resource('comments');
            this.resource('somethings');
        });
    });
});
```

There are multiple resources/routes under the post, either or could be rendered into the outlet.

For your particular case, there are a couple of things we'll need to fix.

First you'll need to mark comments as async, due to your json returning ids.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    magic: DS.attr('string'),
    publishDate: DS.attr('date'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async:true})
});
```

Second we'll want to set up routes for each resource/route that needs a model

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
        return this.store.find('post');
    }
});

App.PostRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('post', params.post_id);
  },
  serialize: function(model){
    return {post_id:model.get('id')};
  }
})

App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return  this.modelFor('post').get('comments');
    }
});
```

And then instead of linking to a single post, we link to `comments`.  And ember will apply the passed in model to the route that has a dynamic model (IE :post_id).

```
{{#each}}
    <h4>{{#link-to 'comments' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}</h4>
{{/each}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wekoxapi/1/edit

Comment: I had to change the router to be:
this.resource('comments', { path: '/'} ); or comments were appearing at /posts/:post_id/comments

Comment: If that's the case, you might just want to delete the route, and use render http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wekoxapi/2/edit

Comment: Suppose we need to use the comments resource by itself: /comments. Is it possible for a resource to handle being an index (findAll) as well as something like posts/1/comments? What would that look like in the Router and Controller? Haven't found a solution for this yet but I am probably missing something.

Comment: Hey guys, I have a form to add new comments at the same page of my details (show) for my posts. So the pattern is `posts/602d036ec600dd06ea49fa1d`. When I try to create the new comment, ember data tries to post in `/comments` which obviously doesn't exist in my API. I tried to add a nested route like `this.route('post', { path: '/posts/:post_id' }, function () {
    this.route('comment');
  });`
and a router like: `async model(params) {
    return this.store.peekRecord('event', params.event_id).get('comments');
  }` but Ember still requesting the same url. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Sorry for poorly formatted snippet. Can't do better in the comments section :S